# API problem while submitting angular springboot form

Tags: angular, spring-boot, api

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHR9r.png)

I got this message after submitting form from angular

this is form.service.ts code

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Formm } from './formm';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FormmService {

  private baseURL = "http://localhost:8080/api/form";

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }
  

  create(form:Formm): Observable<Object>{
    return this.httpClient.post(`${this.baseURL}`, form);
  }

  getById(id: number): Observable<Formm>{
    return this.httpClient.get<Formm>(`${this.baseURL}/${id}`);
  }


}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Don't post images of code but post the code as nicely formatted text. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, as per the exception you're requesting the resource present at `http://localhost:8080` from the content loaded from `http://localhost:4200` which is not allowed by modern browsers as part of their security policy by default. You need to make some changes on the server side, so that server permits those request and same message should be pass on to the browser in form some response headers.

As you mentioned about the `spring` so you can enable the support for cross-origin by using the annotation `@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")` by adding it to your controllers **or** if you want to add for specific controller method, you can achieve the same by adding the annotation to your method only. Another way to add the support for cross-origin globally by creating the bean as following

```
@Bean
public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
        @Override
        public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
            registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("*");
        }
    };
}
```

You can also mention particular origin instead of '*' like for eg: `@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")`

For more details you can also check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS